# Oscillating problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator

I am practicing for my "Mechanics of continuous media" exam.
There is two exercises I couldn't really do yet:

1. A homogeneous meter rod at the 70 cm line is hooked up, and making small amplitude vibrations around its horizontal axis. What is the period of the rod?
   [image]
2. A thin circle of 20 cm radius is placed horizontally on a lathe so that it swings in the plane of the circle as a physical pendulum. Determine the period of low amplitude oscillations. What is the length of the pendulum with the same period?

[image: oscillation side to side]

Can anyone help me with them, with explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: What you know already and what have to tried? These are some basic questions related to oscillations (probably SHM)

Comment: I added some pictures for explaining the problem. I only know the rod is hooked at 70 cm, and its swinging back and forth, and I only know the radius of the circle.

Comment: Do you know about SHM?

Comment: Yes. I just dont know how the rod and the circle is moving, because its not a point-like object.

Comment: if you only know about dynamics of *point-like objects*, and you have a *mechanics of continuous media* exam, your problem is a bit more fundamental than "I can't do these two exercises"!

Comment: Do you understand torques? do you understand center of mass? Draw a free body diagram and calculate the torques about the support point. Write a differential equation for the angular acceleration and extract the frequency from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple physical pendulum when made to execute small oscillations, undergoes SHM. 
I am giving you the idea of approach.
Consider an object suspended in vertical plane , executing oscillations about a horizontal axis.

When finding the time period, displace it a little and try to write the acceleration in terms of displacement. Here we use angular variables.

Let the object be displayed by $\theta$. Let the distance of COM of object from the axis of rotation is d. The moment of inertia is I about that axis.

So the restoring torque is :
$\tau=-mg(d \sin \theta)$ (under \theta angular displacement)

$I\alpha =-mg\theta d$ ($sin\theta \approx \theta$ for small values)

We get equation of SHM, with $\omega =\sqrt{\frac {mgd} {I}}$ and $T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac {I} {mgd}}$